# Tricky use of Get-Acl

Tags: powershell

When using the `Get-ACL` cmdlet it returns a single object that's a bit of a pain to deal with.

```
Path  Owner               Access                                                                                            
----  -----               ------                                                                                            
Test2 Owner               NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Modify, Synchronize                                       
                          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
```

Using something like `(Get-ACL D:\test2).Access` gives much nicer output - an item per permission:

```
FileSystemRights  : Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Due to the way the rest of my script works, this is what I need to be presented with after the `Get-ACL` operation. However, the rest of my script is nested within a `For-Each` off this `Get-ACL` and when using the above example, you can't then call `$acl.AddAccessRule`as this call only seems to work straight off a regular `$acl = Get-ACL "Some Path"` and not `$acl = (get-ACL "some path").Access`

The error I see is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule] does not contain a method named 'AddAccessRule'.
```

Is there a way around this, whereby I am presented with the information in example 2, but can still call the `.AddAccessRule` without having to run another `Get-ACL` just to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
$acl = Get-Acl "Some Path"
$access = $acl.Access

# Do stuff with $access
$acl.AddAccessRule
```